# How to launch EXE when project / solution / studio starts?

Tags: visual-studio, projects

Is there anyway to customize the solution / project file so that it launches an [EXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE) when it's loaded into Visual Studio or, as a second option, when Visual Studio is started? I know I can make a link to a BAT file or similar but I'd rather make it more seamless if possible.

I did check the possibility of adding custom tasks into the project file, since they are just [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) scripts but I couldn't find a suitable event to trigger it on.. They're all build-centric events.

Comment: I believe that MSBuild won't spawn a single task until it is requested to build something.

Comment: Yeah that's what I think as well.. was hoping for some sort of hook anyway.. might do this as a VS add-in instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this question (Enumerate opened windows upon solution loading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804/visual-studio-automation-enumerate-opened-windows-upon-solution-loading)

```
Private Sub SolutionEvents_Opened() Handles SolutionEvents.Opened
  // VB.net code that runs the exe
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I could use something like that but I'd rather use an MSBuild task or similar. It would mean I could check in the exe into the repository, as well as the launch instructions and have it propagate to all the team members without having to create the macro on each machine.